# In Angular2, how can I animate a component which is loaded in an auxiliary route?

Tags: angular

I have a sidebar component which is loaded in a named/auxiliary route. This works fine.

Also, I have some animations setup in this component metadata, for creating a slide in effect. This animation also works fine, when I load this component "normally", for instance when clicking a button.

However, when I add this component in an aux route, the animation doesn't trigger. The component just instantly renders.

Why? How can I fix this? See code below.

**sidebar.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
      selector: 'sidebar',
      templateUrl: 'sidebar.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['sidebar.component.scss'],
      animations: [trigger('slideIn', [
        state('false', style({
          width: '0'
        })),
        state('true', style({
          width: '18.75rem'
        })),
        transition('0 => 1', animate('300ms ease-in')),
        transition('1 => 0', animate('300ms ease-out'))
      ])]
    })
    export class SidebarComponent {
      shouldAnimate: boolean;

      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
         if (this.route.outlet === 'sidebar') {
           this.shouldAnimate = true; // Yes, I do enter here every time
         }
      }
    }
```

**sidebar.component.html**

```
<div id="sidebar"
  [@slideIn]="shouldAnimate">
</div>
```

**from app.routes.ts**

```
{ path: 'profile', outlet: 'sidebar', component: SidebarComponent }
```

**from app.component.ts**

```
<router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself. It turns out, when you're loading a component, the first state it has is `void` and this need to be properly configured in the `animations:` part of the metadata for the component.

So I added a new state which is `void` and also added a transition, from void to 1.

Basically I changed this:

```
trigger('isVisibleChanged', [
  state('false', style({
    width: '0'
  })),
  state('true', style({
    width: '18.75rem'
  })),
  transition('0 => 1', animate('300ms ease-in')),
  transition('1 => 0', animate('300ms ease-out'))
]);
```

to this:

```
trigger('isVisibleChanged', [
  state('void', style({
    width: '0'
  })),
  state('false', style({
    width: '0'
  })),
  state('true', style({
    width: '18.75rem'
  })),
  transition('0 => 1', animate('300ms ease-in')),
  transition('1 => 0', animate('300ms ease-out')),
  transition('void => 1', animate('300ms ease-in'))
]);
```

Comment: Weblurk kudos for finding out about 'void'. You saved me a lot of time.